# View the size of a directory with filezilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Is there a way to see the size of a directory and all it´s content with the Filezilla client?

In my case I want to see the size of a complete WordPress installation (themes, plugins, uploads, backups & etc ... ) but do not see how I can find the complete size.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Is there a way to see the size of a directory and its content with the Filezilla client?

Recursive totals are not implemented for casual usage.

> Directory totals are below each filelist. Number of items and total size for that directory is shown. To get correct results do not have any filename filters enabled.
>
> In case you mean recursive totals, that will not be implemented for casual usage. Due to the way FTP works the overhead is significant and puts a large load on the server (in addition to taking a lot of time).
> That being said, you can use the remote search feature. Just do not enter any search criteria except for the directory.

Source [Check Folder Size & Contents Count?](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=34641)

---

#### Workaround (very inefficient)

> - Click on the folder(s) whose size you want to calculate
> - Click on "Add files to queue"
>
> This will scan all folders and files and add them to the queue.
>
> Then
> look at the queue pane and below it (on the status bar) you should see
> a message indicating the queue size.

Source [How to calculate size of directory on FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041041/3536342), answer by [janusman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174523/janusman)

Comment: Fantastic smart workaround, thanks a lot. Note: Can take a while for folders with several thousands of files.

Answer (score 7):

If willing to use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) (free GUI on Microsoft Windows):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have cPanel, just go to Disk Usage. It automatically calculates the sizes for you. The directory tree displays the size next to each directory/folder. Simply expand the tree to view any directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not everyone has cpanel

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1171909)