# How can I check if all files have transfered successfully in FileZilla?

Tags: filezilla

I have a problem: There is a big Joomla-Site with many files I have to download from the server on my PC. I just marked everything and dragged it over to the panel with my local files to start the download.

However, it did just download one directory of more than ten. Strange enough, but I just dragged every directory over at it's own.

Now every directory is also on my local machine, but I want to verify there's really every file there. Is there some way I can compare the size of the Joomla-site with the downloaded one, or maybe with checksums?

I already googled a lot, but I found nothing.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: According to this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110177) there is draft for `HASH` command as well as some vendor specific alternatives. Your FTP server and client may support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not know how to use a checksum for this, especially since with some settings it could happen that files are changed slightly when uploaded. A relatively safe way (and faster than uploading individual files) would be to upload a zip, check the checksum of that and then unzip it. But if there was an error transferrig a zip, it would probably be broken and not unzip at all.
If you don't have the option to unzip yourself, a good hoster will do it for you. Same if you download, they can create a zip of your installation for you.

If you have access to the backend, you can also use a backup extension. Then download the backup and extract it locally. There are also a few php scripts to create compressed backups.

Anyway, there are still often good reasons to compare folders. I use **PhpStorm** for that. Good ftp programs, such as **WinSCP**, also have folder compare options. Will take a long while. To be really sure, you can (with PhpStorm, at least) even compare content. For a whole Joomla installation, that can take all day, though, even with a fast connection.

Sorry, I see you asked about FileZilla. I have a strong dislike for FileZilla, so have not used it for years. If it does not have folder comparison, dump it.

Comparing sizes would be easy if you had ssh access to the server. But you probably don't - then I would not know how you could do that. See [View the size of a directory with filezilla](https://superuser.com/questions/882817/view-the-size-of-a-directory-with-filezilla) which links to this: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=34641

Answer (score 1):

### As stated on FileZilla Documentation website

To quickly see differences between files on the local machine and the server:

Choose View → Directory Comparison → and either choose:

- **compare file size** or
- **compare modification time**

Enable the ***Hide identical files*** option if you don't want to be distracted by files considered the same on both sides.
Choose: **View** → **Directory Comparison** → **Enable** (or type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>).

> Directories and files **only present** in the local computer or in the remote server : They are highlighted in ***YELLOW*** *in the list of the location where they reside*.

[image]

P.S:

1. ***Please refer to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1268989/370993).***
2. ***For full documentation reading, refer [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Other_Features).***

Answer (score -1):

You could download the whole set again and when prompted choose to overwrite ONLY any existing files where the file size does not match the remote file size.  In that case it would only download any missing or incomplete files.  Check the log for any mention of errors.

Comment: `Is there some way I can compare the size of the Joomla-site with the downloaded one, or maybe with checksums?` Your question does not answer any one of those questions.

Comment: @flolilolilo It does however address **this**: "Now every directory is also on my local machine, but I want to verify there's really every file there."

Comment: There's no guarantee that the file in question was copied correctly, however. And because of the `checksum`-part in the question, I'd think that this is the main question. Otherwise, a simple visual comparison (like a list) would do.

Comment: @flolilolilo I don't disagree, but if that's the OPs main concern then following my suggestion but selecting to replace only local files which are not the same size would work for them too, solving for any incomplete download issues.  I'm just offering the OP a simple solution to their problem, since we have no indication that it really requires some sort of elaborate checksum-based analysis.  Plus, the title of this question is "How Can I Check If All Files Have Transfered Successfully In FileZilla," not how do I generate a crc of files on an FTP host and compare that to a crc of local files.