# Filezilla: Which files were not transferred?

Tags: filezilla

I recently uploaded a large directory tree from my laptop to a cloud instance. Upon completing the upload Filezilla reported 3 files could not be transferred.

Is there some way I can find out *which* files were not transferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a tab at the bottom called "Failed Transfers". If you click on it, it'll show what files failed to transfer. I can't get my own screenshot of the tab at this time, but below is a screenshot from the official website, which shows the failed transfers tab at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Filezilla screenshot from the official website]

Comment: Your answer led me to check View|Transfer queue which was unchecked, apparently by default, in my copy of Filezilla. As I write I'm re-doing the upload and I can see the Failed transfers count ticking up as the upload proceeds.